# choosing a monad at runtime

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm trying to write a two-player game in Haskell, such as checkers.  I envision having types `GameState`, `Move`, and a function `result :: GameState -> Move -> GameState` that defines the game rules.  I want to have both human and automated players, and I figured I'd do this by having a typeclass:

```
class Player p m | p -> m where
  selectMove :: p -> GameState -> m Move
```

where the idea would be that m could be Identity for a basic AI player, IO for a human, State for an AI that maintains state across moves, etc.  The question is how to go from these to the overall game loop.  I figure I could define something like:

```
Player p1 m1, Player p2 m2 => moveList :: p1 -> p2 -> GameState -> m1 m2 [Move]
```

a monadic function that takes in the players and initial state, and returns the lazy list of moves.  But then on top of this let's say I want a text-based interface that, say, allows first selecting each player from a list of possibilities, then causes the game to be played.  So I'd need:

```
playGame :: IO ()
```

I can't see how to define playGame given moveList in a generic way.  Or is my overall approach not right?

EDIT: thinking further about it, I don't even see how to define moveList above.  E.g., if player 1 was a human, so IO, and player 2 was a stateful AI, so State, the first move of player 1 would have type `IO Move`.  Then player 2 would have to take the resulting state of type `IO GameState` and produce a move of type `State IO Move`, and player 1's next move would be of type `IO State IO Move`?  That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

- How to mix a monad-independent chess-playing framework with incremental monad-specific input
- How to specify the monad-specific part at run time

You solve the former problem using a generator, which is a special case of a free monad transformer:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free -- from the "free" package

type GeneratorT a m r = FreeT ((,) a) m r
-- or: type Generator a = FreeT ((,) a)

yield :: (Monad m) => a -> GeneratorT a m ()
yield a = liftF (a, ())
```

`GeneratorT a` is a monad transformer (because `FreeT f` is a monad transformer, for free, when `f` is a `Functor`).  This means we can mix `yield` (which is polymorphic in the base monad), with monad-specific calls by using `lift` to invoke the base monad.

I'll define some fake chess moves just for this example:

```
data ChessMove = EnPassant | Check | CheckMate deriving (Read, Show)
```

Now, I'll define an `IO` based generator of chess moves:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class

ioPlayer :: GeneratorT ChessMove IO r
ioPlayer = forever $ do
    lift $ putStrLn "Enter a move:"
    move <- lift readLn
    yield move
```

That was easy!  We can unwrap the result one move at a time using `runFreeT`, which will only demand the player input a move when you bind the the result:

```
runIOPlayer :: GeneratorT ChessMove IO r -> IO r
runIOPlayer p = do
    x <- runFreeT p -- This is when it requests input from the player
    case x of
        Pure r -> return r
        Free (move, p') -> do
            putStrLn "Player entered:"
            print move
            runIOPlayer p'
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> runIOPlayer ioPlayer
Enter a move:
EnPassant
Player entered:
EnPassant
Enter a move:
Check
Player entered:
Check
...
```

We can do the same thing using the `Identity` monad as the base monad:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

type Free f r = FreeT f Identity r

runFree :: (Functor f) => Free f r -> FreeF f r (Free f r)
runFree = runIdentity . runFreeT
```

NoteThe `transformers-free` packages defines these already (Disclaimer: I wrote it and Edward merged its functionality was merged into the `free` package.  I only keep it for teaching purposes and you should use `free` if possible).

With those in hand, we can define pure chess move generators:

```
type Generator a r = Free ((,) a) r
-- or type Generator a = Free ((,) a)

purePlayer :: Generator ChessMove ()
purePlayer = do
    yield Check
    yield CheckMate

purePlayerToList :: Generator ChessMove r -> [ChessMove]
purePlayerToList p = case (runFree p) of
    Pure _ -> []
    Free (move, p') -> move:purePlayerToList p'

purePlayerToIO :: Generator ChessMove r -> IO r
purePlayerToIO p = case (runFree p) of
    Pure r -> return r
    Free (move, p') -> do
        putStrLn "Player entered: "
        print move
        purePlayerToIO p'
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> purePlayerToList purePlayer
[Check, CheckMate]
```

Now, to answer your next question, which is how to choose the base monad at run time.  This is easy:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Pick a monad!"
    whichMonad <- getLine
    case whichMonad of
        "IO"     -> runIOPlayer ioPlayer
        "Pure"   -> purePlayerToIO purePlayer
        "Purer!" -> print $ purePlayerToList purePlayer
```

Now, here is where things get tricky.  You actually want two players, and you want to specify the base monad for both of them independently.  To do this, you need a way to retrieve one move from each player as an action in the `IO` monad and save the rest of the player's move list for later:

```
step
 :: GeneratorT ChessMove m r
 -> IO (Either r (ChessMove, GeneratorT ChessMove m r))
```

The `Either r` part is in case the player runs out of moves (i.e. reaches the end of their monad), in which case the `r` is the block's return value.

This function is specific to each monad `m`, so we can type class it:

```
class Step m where
    step :: GeneratorT ChessMove m r
         -> IO (Either r (ChessMove, GeneratorT ChessMove m r))
```

Let's define some instances:

```
instance Step IO where
    step p = do
        x <- runFreeT p
        case x of
            Pure r -> return $ Left r
            Free (move, p') -> return $ Right (move, p')

instance Step Identity where
    step p = case (runFree p) of
        Pure r -> return $ Left r
        Free (move, p') -> return $ Right (move, p')
```

Now, we can write our game loop to look like:

```
gameLoop
 :: (Step m1, Step m2)
 => GeneratorT ChessMove m1 a
 -> GeneratorT ChessMove m2 b
 -> IO ()
gameLoop p1 p2 = do
    e1 <- step p1
    e2 <- step p2
    case (e1, e2) of
        (Left r1, _) -> <handle running out of moves>
        (_, Left r2) -> <handle running out of moves>
        (Right (move1, p2'), Right (move2, p2')) -> do
            <do something with move1 and move2>
            gameLoop p1' p2'
```

And our `main` function just selects which players to use:

```
main = do
    p1 <- getStrLn
    p2 <- getStrLn
    case (p1, p2) of
        ("IO", "Pure") -> gameLoop ioPlayer purePlayer
        ("IO", "IO"  ) -> gameLoop ioPlayer ioPlayer
        ...
```

I hope that helps.  That was probably a bit over kill (and you can probably use something simpler than generators), but I wanted to give a general tour of cool Haskell idioms that you can sample from when designing your game.  I type-checked all but the last few code blocks, since I couldn't come up with a sensible game logic to test on the fly.

You can learn more about [free monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) and [free monad transformers](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/free-monad-transformers.html) if those examples didn't suffice.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems like a pretty nice general solution.  One question: how would you implement step for a State monad?

Comment: I got four lines in before I thought "I bet this is Gabriel's answer" :)

Comment: @bhaskarama You don't!  You would actually write something of type: `StateT s (Free ChessMove) r`, use `runStateT` to convert that to `Free ChessMove r`, and then pass that as a "pure" player.  Not all monads that you extend your player with belong in the base monad.

Comment: Really?  But how would the player's state get passed across moves then?

Comment: @bhaskarama Sorry, my response was mistaken.  I forgot that your stateful player still has to interact with the other one to decide their moves.  That interaction can only be done in the `IO` monad.  The only way to change the monad within which the two players two interact is to change the base monad that every `step` function targets.

Comment: So if you want to add the possibility thread state across moves you need to change step's signature to `_ -> StateT s (IO (Either _ _))`, and `s` must be the same for both players. Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 6):

My advice has two main parts:

1. Skip defining a new type class.
2. Program to the interfaces defined by existing type classes.

For the first part, what I mean is you should consider creating a data type like

```
data Player m = Player { selectMove :: m Move }
-- or even
type Player m = m Move
```

What the second part means is to use classes like `MonadIO` and `MonadState` to keep your `Player` values polymorphic, and choose an appropriate monad instance only at the end after combining all the players. For example, you might have

```
computerPlayer :: MonadReader GameState m => Player m
randomPlayer :: MonadRandom m => Player m
humanPlayer :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader GameState m) => Player m
```

Perhaps you will find there are other players you want, too. Anyway, the point of this is that once you've created all these players, if they are typeclass polymorphic as above, you may choose a particular monad that implements all the required classes and you are done. For example, for these three, you might choose `ReaderT GameState IO`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I still don't see how to write the overall game loop as described above given these players though.  I.e., how would I, based on user input, decide what type each player was and then play out the game?

Comment: @bhaskarama After implementing several polymorphic players, you choose a single, monomorphic type and specialize them all to that type. The game loop then also uses that monomorphic type.

Comment: Ok, and sorry if this is a basic question, but how would this specialization work?  E.g., if there are players in IO, Identity, as well as maybe one stateful player that caches results between moves, in a monad State Cache, and another stateful one that adjusts its playing style over time, say State Style.  What would be the single monomorphic type in this case, and how would one go about specializing the players to that type?

Comment: @bhaskarama As I said in my answer: rather than using `IO Move`, `Identity Move`, and `State Style Move`, you should use `MonadIO m => m Move`, `Monad m => m Move`, and `MonadState Style m => m Move`; then one monomorphic type that implements all these interfaces is (for example) `StateT Style IO Move`.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I guess a limitation of this one compared to Gabriel's solution is that you have to know the monads you want to use ahead of time; e.g., if I wanted to now write a player using a different type of state I'd have to change the main loop.  But it's certainly simpler.